# Why does GDM lock screen allows entering partially correct password to login?

Tags: gnome, login, opensuse, screen-lock, gdm

I am using GNOME 3.34.2 on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed(20191221) with GDM. I locked my screen and was able to get back in just by entering the portion of correct password greater than a certain threshold length. For example, if my password is of length 13, I could log in just by entering the correct sequence of characters with length greater than or equal to 8.

I couldn't find anything related to this behavior either here on StackExchange or on google.

Why does this happen?

Is there a way to override this behavior?

Does this happen only up till a certain time after locking the screen?

Comment: I couldn't find anything related to this behavior either here on StackExchange or on google.

Comment: Does this happen at login too?

Comment: @roaima yes it does, I just tried.

Comment: Sounds like your password's [DES encrypted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2181568/2072269). How do you set your password? Who administers the system?

Comment: DES was my thought exactly, too

Comment: @muru I administer the system, I had set the password during installation. I am the only user.

Comment: Check the encrypted password in `/etc/shadow`. Does it begin with `$n$`?

Comment: @muru yes the root password begins with ``$n$`` where n is a single-digit number.

Comment: Are you logging in as root in gdm?

Comment: @muru nope, I am logging in as the only user(who has root access)

Comment: Then you should be checking your user's password in `/etc/shadow`

Comment: @muru no, the user password's hash doesn't begin with ``$n$``